# how to cache authentication information in WCF?

Tags: wcf, performance, security, authentication, membership-provider

I'm using Message/Username/Custom MembershipProvider for my WCF service authentication.

by default, WCF authenticates every call from the client.

My Custom MembershipProvider access database for checking username/password.

so for each call from the client the service has to access database for authentication, and this might have performance implications as the number of calls increase.

Is there a default way to cache this authentication information(perhaps by creating a ticket and using that ticket for further authentication as in ASP.NET)?

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely could use [ASP.NET Forms Auth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386582.aspx) for WCF calls, keeping the token as a cookie that's passed with every request.

Comment: I can see that you can create a Authentication Service in WCF, how can I enforce authentication on other WCF services? i.e. enforce the server to check if there is a valid ticket in the cookie when users try to access other WCF service.

Comment: You don't even have to use an Authentication Service, really. That's just for logging in via WCF service call. As long as you use standard ASP.NET authorization rules for the URL of your .SVC files (you can fine-grain it with the [location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx) element), ASP.NET will handle auth for any request that goes through those URLs.

Comment: I can deny access to those WCF Services by using location element, but I can't grant access even after I log in. because WCF doesn't seem to send cookie information with each request. I think I could take cookie information after login and add that to each request's header manually. is there another way to do it? thanks.